# How to trigger block from any of multiple signal producers?

Tags: ios, reactive-swift

How do I trigger one block of code whenever any of a set of SignalProducers change? In other words, how do I get rid of my current redundant code:

```
property1.producer.startWithValues { (value) in 
    // do stuff with property1.value and property2.value
}

property2.producer.startWithValues { (value) in 
    // do the same stuff with property1.value and property2.value
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of context? For example, does the code block use both properties' values or only the value that gets a passed in to the closure?

Comment: Sorry, the block uses both property's values. I've modified the above to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` to create a new property that contains both values:

```
let prop = property1.combineLatest(with: property2)
prop.producer.startWithValues { (val1, val2) in
    // do stuff here
}
```

If either value changes, the block will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the block of code as a variable, then you would simply assign that variable to `property1.producer.startWithValues`.

Comment: You mean save the block as a variable, and then use it in both places? It seems like there should be a way to have a single block run when either property changes.. Some way to say "if either property changes, run this block"...