# How to trigger block from any of > 2 signal producers?

Tags: ios, reactive-swift

I see in [How to trigger block from any of multiple signal producers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372792/how-to-trigger-block-from-any-of-multiple-signal-producers) that 2 signal producers can be combined using combineLatest.

But what if there's 3 or more signal producers, where you want access to all 3 values?

I tried:

```
 let prop = property1.combineLatest(with: property2).combineLatest(with: property3)

 prop.producer.startWithValues { ((val1, val2), val3) in
     // do stuff here
 }
```

But I get "Closure truple parameter does not support destructuring". Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
 let prop = SignalProducer.combineLatest(property1, property2, property3)
```